# Acing a copy of a unique card that you have in play

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

Say that you have a character or deed in play that does not have the non-unique keyword (which are most dudes and deeds), and another card of the same name in your hand. You would not be able to play this second one because the character is unique. Similarly, if the card on the table is aced, you still cannot play the same card because it is unique.

But what happens if you have a unique card in play and then you try to ace the duplicate in your hand, either intentionally through something like [Gomorra Parish](http://dtdb.co/en/card/01057), or forcibly through something like [This'll Hurt in the Mornin'](http://dtdb.co/en/card/05038).

Is this permitted? Does anything happen when you have a dude in play and then a duplicate gets aced to Boot Hill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special happens and the unique character in play is permitted to remain in play, despite a duplicate being added to Boot Hill. The uniqueness rule only applies to bringing cards into play, not to cards that are already in play.

> You can put more than one copy in your deck, but you can’t bring a unique card into play if you own another card with the same name that is either already in play or in your Boot Hill. (DTR Rulebook, Page 14 Uniqueness)

This is corroborated by [a ruling on the AEG forums](http://www.alderac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=375&t=114319).